# Validation and Message Joining Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, message

I've tried to implement a validation service to my project. My Validator Code looks like this:

```
public class UserValidator implements Validator{

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Ort.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Ort ort = (Ort) target;
        if((ort.getcountryname().length() == 0) && (ort.getzip().length() == 0))
        {
        errors.reject("error.zip");
        errors.reject("error.countryname");
        }

    }

}
```

I have an message xml with he following entries:
Code:

```
......
error.zip=There is an Error at Zip-Code
error.countryname=There is an Error at Countryname
```

Everything works fine. I make an outprint on my jsp like this:
Code:

```
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="error message" element="div"/>
```

My HTML Code looks like this if I get an error:
Code:

```
There is an Error at Zip-Code<br>There is an Error at Countryname
```

My Question:
How can I join the message so that i get an outprint on my jsp with looks so:
Code:

```
There is an Error at Zip-Code, There is an Error at Countryname
```

Can i do somethink like that in my validation class?

Code:

```
......
        errors.reject("error.zip"+"error.countryname");
......
```

Comment: Sorry that I must say it, but you should defintly have a look at JSR 303 Bean Validation Support for Spring.

Comment: Hi thanks for that reply:) But in all documents I can't find an answer how I can combine message strings. So my question is can i create a type of object which contains all the message strings i like? So that i can make somethink like that: TheObjectIdontKnow = name = new TheObjectIdontKnow(); name = ("A normal String"+"message.from.messagefile"+","+"SecondMessage.from.messagefile"; Hope you can help me;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mixed two concepts:

- how the error messages are stored in the errors object (`errors.reject("error.zip"+"error.countryname")`)
- how they are printed `There is an Error at Zip-Code, There is an Error at Countryname`

If you want to change the way they are printed, then you have to change the `form:errors` tag, but NOT the way you add the messages to the error object! (In contrast: if you want to change the messages itself, then changing the output would be the wrong way.)

So remove the `<br/>` from the output and replace it by `,` you just need to specify the `delimiter` attribute of the `form:errors` tag:

```
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="error message" element="div" delimiter",&nbsp;"/>
```

@see [Spring Reference Appendix G.4 The errors tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#spring-form.tld.errors)